# Build maven javafx project like ant

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have a small question. I don't know whether it is stupid. I had a legacy ant java swing project. I was able to migrate it to javafx with maven and I can build it with dependencies and run. but the thing is when I build it with dependencies, application size is little bit high. The thing is I wanted to deploy it to many places through the network but it take time and consume bandwidth. I wanted to deploy it like in ant where ant build lib separately and project separately so that I only needed to deploy the executable jar with out supporting library files. Someone can enlighten me on that, so thankful.

Comment: You might shave a bit off the dependency issue were you to 'go modern' and build with modules and `jlink`

Comment: See the tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for more.

Comment: The build tool doesn't matter here. What matters is that your clients have all dependencies present/"installed". How did your project handle deployment previously? Because all that _should_ have changed with regards to deployment is the need to ensure JavaFX is present on client computers, as unlike Swing, JavaFX is not part of Java SE. If you control the network and the clients, then this is an administration/IT responsibility. Otherwise, you have to instruct your clients what else they need to install, probably with instructions on _how_ to install those things, to get the app working.

Comment: Or your deployment strategy can include the dependencies, including JavaFX, with your application. In that case, you may just have to accept the increased bandwidth usage.

Comment: “I was able to migrate it to javafx with maven and I can build it with dependencies and run.” -> how did you do that? What is your Maven project file? What is your build command and run command?  How do your users get the app?  Do they install it on their machine?  Does the app have prerequisites like a Java runtime or JavaFX modules installed on the machine? How do your users get and install the prerequisites?  How do they update the app or the stuff used to run it?  What Java and JavaFX versions are required?  Which OS type and versions are supported?  Edit your question to improve it.